# Drupal upgrade to 8.2.3 failed

Tags: drupal, drush

I had a fresh installation of Drupal 8.2.2 running and followed https://www.drupal.org/node/2550801 to update it with drush, but I got:

```
$ drush pm-update drupal
Update information last refreshed: Fri, 11/18/2016 - 22:02
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                   
 Drupal  8.2.2              8.2.3             SECURITY UPDATE available 


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Drupal root path is not writable.                                                                                                    [error]
/var/www/html $ drush pm-update drupal
Update information last refreshed: Fri, 11/18/2016 - 22:02
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                   
 Drupal  8.2.2              8.2.3             SECURITY UPDATE available 


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 8.2.3.
Backups were saved into the directory /home/www-data/drush-backups/drupal/20161118222811/drupal.                                        [ok]
[18-Nov-2016 22:28:41 UTC] Error: Call to undefined function drupal_get_installed_schema_version() in /var/www/html/core/includes/install.inc on line 80 #0 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal/update.inc(111): drupal_load_updates()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(462): update_main()
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_updatedb()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(458): drush_main()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(365): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#10 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#11 {main}
Error: Call to undefined function drupal_get_installed_schema_version() in drupal_load_updates() (line 80 of /var/www/html/core/includes/install.inc).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully updated drupal 8.2.2  to the new version 8.2.3.
Please find the steps

```
$ drush pm-update drupal
Update information last refreshed: Mon, 11/21/2016 - 12:05
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                   
 Drupal  8.2.2              8.2.3             SECURITY UPDATE available 


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y

Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 8.2.3.
Backups were saved into the directory /home/drush-backups/d8_dbupdate_nov21/20161121110543/drupal.                                   [ok]

The following updates are pending:

system module : 
  8202 -   Clear caches due to behavior change in MachineName element. 

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y

Performing system_update_8202                                                                                                               [ok]

Cache rebuild complete.                                                                                                                     [ok]

Finished performing updates.                                                                                                                [ok]
```

Updating drush to the latest version may help to resolve the issue.

```
 $ drush version
```

Drush Version   :  8.1.7

Also compare the php version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files are readable by your web server. It could be that core/includes/schema.inc isn't readable (which is where drupal_get_installed_schema_version lives).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I just faced it. In my case it appears I just had to launch the drush command with privileges adding `sudo`